# List Inheritance Change Breaks Backwards Compatibility

Tags: c#, .net-4.5

Recently I ran across a class in a supporting library that was defined as:

`public class CustomCollection<T> : ObservableCollection<T>`

In going through the code, I realized that it was better for usability and performance to instead extend from list:

`public class CustomCollection<T> : List<T>`

In our implementation, nothing specific to ObservableCollection was actually used, so I thought that this change would "just work" across all consumers. When I updated the main application to consume the new library where CustomCollection extends from List, I ran across the following exception:

`Collection is read only`

This was surprising to me because, in the main application, I was able to do the standard `myCustomCollection.Add(someItem)` without any issue. It's only when the code is executed via another (not recompiled) library that causes the issue, ex:

```
+ Main application
  - Direct ussage  of CustomCollection = Success
  - Call to library that was not recompiled
    -- Usage for CustomCollection fails on .Add(...) with read-only error
```

Does anyone have any insight into why this occurring? `ObservableCollection` extends from `Collection`, which is actually backed by a `List<T>` internally, so I'm not sure what code path is now executing causing the read only error.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the source code you have as a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.

Comment: That's going to be really hard for someone to do. You have to put the CustomCollection into a library, consume that library into another library, and then consume both of the libraries in a main application. Nobody is going to do that.

Comment: Rarely is it necessary to inherit from a collection type.  Instead it's better to use composition over inheritance.  Had your class been done that way you would have been changing internal implementation details instead of breaking the API.

Comment: That's interesting ... when we did this we definitely got a read only exception. Did you use .NET 4.5.2 or some other framework?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simplify the scenario. Create a console app:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Debugger.Launch();

    var c = new CustomCollection<string>();
    c.Add("Foo");
}
```

And create a class library which you reference from the console app, with just one line in it:

```
public class CustomCollection<T> : System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<T> { }
```

Run the app with a breakpoint on `c.Add()` and hit F10 to verify the program. Now to reproduce the error:

- Change `System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection` to `System.Collections.Generic.List`
- **Only** build the class library (right-click the project, select Build).
- Go to the output directory and copy the DLL into the directory of the console application's executable, overwriting the old one it's compiled against.
- Now run the executable by double-clicking it, and you'll be asked whether you want to debug in your already running instance of Visual Studio.
- Attach to the program and hit F5 to continue, and now your exception will be thrown.

On .NET Core 3.1, the above steps lead to:

> Exception of type 'System.ExecutionEngineException' was thrown.

Looking at the IL, it's clear why:

```
// [20 7 - 20 71]
IL_0012: newobj       instance void class [ClassLibWithCollections]ClassLibWithCollections.CustomCollection`1<string>::.ctor()
IL_0017: stloc.0      // V_0
IL_0018: ldloc.0      // V_0
IL_0019: ldstr        "Foo"
IL_001e: callvirt     instance void class [System.Runtime]System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection`1<string>::Add(!0/*string*/)
IL_0023: nop
```

It gets compiled to a virtual call to `Collection<T>.Add(T)`, but the `List<T>`-derived `CustomCollection<T>` does *not* inherit from `Collection<T>`, so the runtime throws that exception.

To fix this, you have to compile users of this type, because you've made a breaking change.

Other exceptions could be thrown as well when you change base types like this. The point is: the call goes to the base class (or one of that class's base classes), and if you change a base class, that method may throw an exception or not exist at all.

Comment: Well then, we are evidently really ... dumb. Somehow we were thinking that List inherits collection. Oops

Comment: @debracey Well to be fair, it *does* implement `ICollection<T>` - but not `Collection<T>`

Comment: @Matthew yeah, `((ICollection<string>)c).Add("Bar");` does the trick.